# How do I make a ball bounce off the sides of the canvas?

Tags: javascript

[Here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/problem-3-a-bouncy-ball/5123011626336256) is the link to my project so far.

I want to make a ball(an ellipse) bounce around all four walls of the canvas and as this happens I would also like to change the colour of the ball and speed after each bounce(randomly of course). P.S I want the ball to continue bouncing around the canvas off all four walls. Thanks for the help!!

This is the code I have tried. It gets the ball across the y-axis from top to bottom and keeps going, but I don't know how to get it to bounce off the left and right sides. I would just like the ball to bounce on all four sides in a clockwise direction(left wall, top, right wall, bottom, etc etc.)

**EDITED**

```
// position of the ball
var y = 33;
// how far the ball moves every time
var speed = 2;

draw = function() {
background(127, 204, 255);

fill(66, 66, 66);
ellipse(200, y, 50, 50);

// move the ball
y = y + speed;

if (y > 371) 
    {
        speed = -5;
    }

if (y < 31) 
    {
        speed = 5;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the finished project.

```
noStroke();

// The Speed Of The Ball When It Starts
    var initialSpeedX = 5;
    var initialSpeedY = -3;

// The Current Speed Of The Ball
    var ballSpeedX = +initialSpeedX;
    var ballSpeedY = -initialSpeedY;

// The Current Location Of The Ball
    var ballX = 0;
    var ballY = 0;

// Check If The Ball Is Moving
    var ballMoving = false;

var draw = function() {
    background(120, 228, 255);

// Move The Ball
    if (ballMoving) {
    ballX += ballSpeedX;
    ballY += ballSpeedY;

    }
    else {
    ballX = mouseX;
    ballY = 465;
    }

// Draw The Ball
    ellipse(ballX, ballY, 70, 70);

// Check If Ball Has Hit The Top
    if (ballY <= 35) {
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
    fill(243, 255, 10);
    }

// Check If The Ball Has Hit The Left Wall
    if (ballX <= 35) {
    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
    fill(235, 135, 12);
    }

// Check If The Ball Has Hit The Right Wall
    if (ballX >= 465) {
    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    }

// Check If Ball Has Hit The Bottom
    if (ballY >= 465) {
    ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
    fill(0, 255, 9);
    }
    };

// When The Mouse Is Clicked
    var mouseClicked = function() {
    if (!ballMoving) {

// Reset The Ball Speed
    ballSpeedX = initialSpeedX;
    ballSpeedY = initialSpeedY;
    ballMoving = true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems with your code. The curly brace that closes the first if was typed in the wrong place. To make the ball bounce, just multiply your speed by -1. Take a look:

```
// The position of the ball
var x = 25;

// How far the ball moves every time
var speed = 3;

var draw = function() {

    background(47, 222, 126);

    // The ball
    fill(48, 46, 48);
    ellipse(x, 200, 50, 50);

    // Moves the ball
    x = x + speed;

    if (x > 375) {
        speed = -speed;
    } else if (x < 214) {
        speed = -speed;
    }

};
```

This is a more complete example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById( "myCanvas" );
var context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
var width = 400;
var height = 200;

var ball = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    radius: 25,
    xSpeed: 3,
    ySpeed: 3,
    draw: function( ctx ) {
     ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc( this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI );
        ctx.fill();
    },
    move: function() {
        this.x += this.xSpeed;
        this.y += this.ySpeed;
    }
}

setInterval( function(){
 
    context.clearRect( 0, 0, width, height );
    context.strokeRect( 0, 0, width, height );
    
    ball.move();
    
    // right 
    if ( ball.x + ball.radius >= width ) {
     ball.x = width - ball.radius;
        ball.xSpeed = -ball.xSpeed;
    }
    
    // left
    if ( ball.x - ball.radius <= 0 ) {
     ball.x = ball.radius;
        ball.xSpeed = -ball.xSpeed;
    }
    
    // down
    if ( ball.y + ball.radius >= height ) {
     ball.y = height - ball.radius;
        ball.ySpeed = -ball.ySpeed;
    }
    
    // up
    if ( ball.y - ball.radius <= 0 ) {
     ball.y = ball.radius;
        ball.ySpeed = -ball.ySpeed;
    }
    
    ball.draw( context );
    
}, 10 );
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

And this have some physics simulation...

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById( "myCanvas" );
var context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
var width = 400;
var height = 200;
var gravity = 1;

var ball = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    radius: 25,
    xSpeed: 1,
    ySpeed: 1,
    friction: 0.99,
    elasticity: 0.9,
    draw: function( ctx ) {
     ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc( this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI );
        ctx.fill();
    },
    move: function() {
        this.x += this.xSpeed;
        this.y += this.ySpeed;
    }
}

setInterval( function(){
 
    context.clearRect( 0, 0, width, height );
    context.strokeRect( 0, 0, width, height );
    
    ball.move();
    
    // right 
    if ( ball.x + ball.radius >= width ) {
     ball.x = width - ball.radius;
        ball.xSpeed = -ball.xSpeed * ball.elasticity;
    }
    
    // left
    if ( ball.x - ball.radius <= 0 ) {
     ball.x = ball.radius;
        ball.xSpeed = -ball.xSpeed * ball.elasticity;
    }
    
    // down
    if ( ball.y + ball.radius >= height ) {
     ball.y = height - ball.radius;
        ball.ySpeed = -ball.ySpeed * ball.elasticity;
    }
    
    // up
    if ( ball.y - ball.radius <= 0 ) {
     ball.y = ball.radius;
        ball.ySpeed = -ball.ySpeed * ball.elasticity;
    }
    
    ball.xSpeed = ball.friction;
    ball.ySpeed = ball.ySpeed + ball.friction + gravity;
    
    ball.draw( context );
    
}, 10 );
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do this in Khan Academy? It doesn't allow the use of  'document.getElementById( "myCanvas" );' and it doesn't allow you to redefine height and width as a variable. Thanks for your help! The snippet you provided works perfectly, just not in Khan Academy :/

Comment: @JMS03 is this some kind of exercise? If so, you will need to code as the exercise requires. The corrected version of your code should work. What is going wrong?

Comment: No, it's just some project I thought of and had seen similar projects. Just thought I might give it a go.

Comment: I've changed my code slightly, now it goes up and down on the y-axis. Now, need to find a way to make it bounce off the left and right walls on the x-axis.